# How to get html preview result as a string from html element with jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to get HTML preview result from the jsoup element. Let say I have the jsoup element that has the following html code:

Element's HTML Code:

```
<div class="code-container">
<div id="highlighter_245626" class="syntaxhighlighter nogutter   night">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="code">
<div class="container">
<div class="line number1 index0 alt2"><code class="comments">// C++ program for implementation of FCFS </code></div>
<div class="line number2 index1 alt1"><code class="comments">// scheduling </code></div>
<div class="line number3 index2 alt2"><code class="preprocessor">#include&lt;bits/stdc++.h&gt; </code></div>
<div class="line number4 index3 alt1"><code class="keyword bold">using</code> <code class="keyword bold">namespace</code> <code class="plain">std; </code></div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div></div>
```

HTML preview result string:

```
// C++ program for implementation of FCFS
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
```

I have tried to get HTML preview string with Element.Text() And I have the following problems:

- Broken line endings
- Irregular spacings

Is there a better way to get HTML preview result as a string from HTML element with jsoup?

Comment: did you tried `driver.getPageSource();` ?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I confuse jsoup and selenium because my program consists of selenium and jsoup.I have edited question.thanks for your understanding.

Comment: so did you tried `element.outerHtml()`?

Comment: Thanks, again.element.outerHtml() will fetch the HTML source of the element instead of fetching the HTML preview result of the element. I also add the example about what I mean as "HTML preview result "

Comment: So what about this: Jsoup.parse(element.outerHtml()).toString();

Comment: This code transfers the HTML code of the document into a string. Not getting preview result of the HTML element.

Comment: Aha, I think I get what you want, let me post is as answer and you check it works or not.

Answer (score 2):

This will preserve line breaks for you:

```
public static String cleanPreserveLineBreaks(String bodyHtml) {

    // get pretty printed html with preserved br and p tags
    String prettyPrintedBodyFragment = Jsoup.clean(bodyHtml, "", Whitelist.none().addTags("br", "p"), new OutputSettings().prettyPrint(true));
    // get plain text with preserved line breaks by disabled prettyPrint
    return Jsoup.clean(prettyPrintedBodyFragment, "", Whitelist.none(), new OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works on my example by only preserving line breaks, I need to a general solution that can get HTML result(preview string) from HTML code with Java. Maybe I need a different tool for that. Any idea appreciated.

Comment: @my-lord I think you should handle it by your own! but I'm not expert in jsoup. maybe you should use other tools or would be better solutions for this.